# Tables with no rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-enterprise-manager

When I create any new tables in oracle 11g enterprise manager or sql plus 
it results in something like this:

-there is no row count (no event zero)

When I insert data to the table by SQL*plus, it says that rows are inserted but when I reconnect by SQL*Plus they all disappear and also the row count in the Enterprise manager still remains blank!

[image: Blank Row Count in Enterprise Manager]

I did commit and I also made sure my table is not temporary!

any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `row count` you are referring to does not reflect actual number of rows in the table. It is a statistic collected  by database at regular interval (first being upon table creation). You can refer to `last analyzed` column which indicates the time when this `row count` data is collected.

By default new statistics are collected when there is 10% change in table. You can force stats collection on table using some DBA tools (PL SQL procedures to start stats collection).
Note: the data you see in Enterprise Manager is the data avilable `DBA_TABLES` or `USER_TABLES` view.

You can check actual rows on table by issuing below command in sqlplus

`select count(*) from your_table_here;`